# Works with libc++, segmentation fault with listdc++. [MacOs Sierra, Boost, Clang]

Tags: c++, macos, clang, libstdc++, libc++

I want to get Mitsuba working on my Mac, I manage to compile it and I got an error at the runtime. I tried to manage to generate a simple test, to show you the bug :

```
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
        fs::path test = fs::canonical("/Users/Stephane-lb/Projects/");
        return 0;
}
```

if I compile it using the following command, everything is working 
    clang++ boostTest.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system

but if I use:
    clang++ boostTest.cpp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -stdlib=libstdc++

I think it is happening because boost was compiled using homebrew so using libc++ and I want to use libstdc++. Is there any ways to make these two working together ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Stephane-lb

Comment: Compile Boost with libstdc++...?

Comment: Why not just use libc++?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

@EricWF : if i do this, I have a much strange error, that I did not succeed to reproduce. This one appear during the compilation : "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/complex:1301:42: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INFINITY' "

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Yes this is the idea I had too, and did not really find how to change that in the build system provide by boost yet ...

Comment: @Stephane-lb Huh, well that seems like a serious error in libc++, which I am very interested in fixing but I can't reproduce on my own. Would you be willing to send me the full diagnostic stack?

Comment: @EricWF : Thanks for your help, just create a gist for it : https://gist.github.com/stephane-lb/16b925afb8d8be3df7a6ba709c9857e7#file-trace-sh

Comment: @Stephane-lb I don't see any reason why that's not working. `INFINITY` should be defined by `math.h` which `<complex>` includes. My best guess is it's either hitting some weird cyclical include or somebody is undef-ing `INFINITY`.

Comment: @EricWF Thank you very much! You solved it. A quick "ag undef INFINITY"  give the line which created the issue. I did not think about this option.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did what you suggest too, and it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Write an answer please

Comment: @Stephane-lb Phew! I did some grep "undef INFINITY" for the sources I could see like Eigen but didn't find anything.